# TeamCity REST Api supported requests and names of parameters

Tags: rest, teamcity

I was trying to use the REST API of TeamCity but i can't find a list of all supported requests and the names of parameters. I wanted to look it up in their official documentation   (https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/REST+API)
where a link to exactly this list is provided
(http://teamcity:8111/app/rest/application.wadl)
but i just can't connect to it. Seems like the page is down.

I have googled all kinds of stuff in the hope to find this list somewhere else but i couldn't find anything smart.

Does anyone know where to find such a list or can provide one? That would be fantastic.

Thanks

Comment: Me bing stupid and all trying to access a local server which wasn't running, thinking i was connection to some public server when i obsly wasn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find available API on the public teamcity: 
https://teamcity.jetbrains.com/app/rest/swagger.json

You can navigate through the response inside the `paths` and look at supported methods, and required parameters for each API.

You can also access to the .wadl on the public teamcity server:
https://teamcity.jetbrains.com/app/rest/application.wadl

When you are inside the documentation of teamcity, they use `teamcity:8111` as your own teamcity, installed on your server.

> The URL examples on this page assume that your TeamCity server web UI is accessible via the http://teamcity:8111 URL.

Comment: Yea i figured it was just me being retarded thinking for some reason i was accessing some public server of theirs when using the link i couldn't connect to. Clicked today in my brain when i looked at it again... Thanks anyways

Comment: No problem, I think getting informations on how to get the swagger.json or application.wadl can help people to decide wether or not they should upgrade to a new version of TeamCity.

Answer (score 0):

If you [download a copy of teamcity](https://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/download/), start a copy of the server, and then connect to `/app/rest/application.wadl`, you will probably get a copy of representation.